# After adding a join in query - it doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I had this query which stackoverflow member have helped me on

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ProductTrans
    WHERE (`ProductName` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`PalletSpace` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

I then added a join which gave me this

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT PalletSpaces.*, ProductTrans.*
FROM PalletSpaces INNER JOIN ProductTrans ON PalletSpaces.PalletSpaceID = ProductTrans.PalletSpace;
        WHERE (`ProductTrans.ProductName` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`PalletSpaces.PalletSpace` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

This gives me the error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (`ProductTrans.ProductName` LIKE '%me%') OR (`PalletSpaces.PalletSpace` LI' at line 3

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's because of a semicolon before `where` (voting to close).

Comment: That returns Unknown column 'ProductTrans.ProductName' in 'where clause'

Comment: `ProductTrans.ProductName` is a column that your new query references. You need to make sure that only the columns defined in your database are used in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.*
     , t.*
  FROM PalletSpaces s
  JOIN ProductTrans t
    ON s.PalletSpaceID = t.PalletSpace
 WHERE t.ProductName LIKE '%$query%' OR s.PalletSpace LIKE '%$query%';
```

Comment: That doesnt return an error - but doesnt give any results? Thanks

Comment: There are results - its the table that is gone wierd - the rows are 0px tall i think - even though I havent specified it

Comment: Should I start another question? The query error has gone Thanks

Comment: Only you can answer that! :-)

Comment: Just a question - should I replace the s & t with the table names? Or leave it like they are?

Comment: You're straying in to the realm of opinion. In my opinion, an assiduous use of table/column aliases is always good.

Answer (score 0):

```
... paces.PalletSpaceID = ProductTrans.PalletSpace;
                                                  ^----
```

that semicolon TERMINATES the query. Anything that comes after it is treated as a completely separate/new query. Since the PHP MySQL driver forbids multiple queries in a single `query()` call, you get the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to remove the semicolon after JOIN statement:

`SELECT PalletSpaces.*, ProductTrans.*
FROM PalletSpaces 
INNER JOIN ProductTrans ON PalletSpaces.PalletSpaceID = ProductTrans.PalletSpace
WHERE (`ProductTrans.ProductName`LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`PalletSpaces.PalletSpace`LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

From your code

```
FROM 
    PalletSpaces 
INNER JOIN 
    ProductTrans ON PalletSpaces.PalletSpaceID = ProductTrans.PalletSpace;
WHERE 
    (`ProductTrans.ProductName` LIKE '%".$query."%') 
    OR (`PalletSpaces.PalletSpace` LIKE '%".$query."%')") 
    OR die(mysql_error());
```

This gives me the error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to

Remove the semicolon after `ProductTrans.PalletSpace` before `WHERE`